# Using Passport-google behind proxy

Tags: node.js, iis-7, proxy, openid, passport.js

I'm using Passport-google to login users in `example.com:3000`. It works great. But if I put the Node.js server behind a proxy (IIS7; don't ask why, I had to), and access to my site in `example.com` (not in `example.com:3000`), I can't login with Passport-google. My RewriteRule in IIS:

```
Pattern (.*) 
{HTTP_HOST} Matches myserver.com
{SERVER_PORT} Does not match 3000
Rewrite URL: http://127.0.0.1:3000/{R:1}
```

The error I got:

```
Cannot GET /accounts/o8/ud?
```

Also I have the same problem with Passport-twitter, and Passport-facebook.

I think I should set some other rule in IIS, or set some proxy settings in Passport.js, or OpenID, but haven't figured out yet. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IIS proxy had a bad configuration. under Application Request Routing (ARR) / Server proxy settings `Reverse rewrite host in response headers` was switched on, so when passport sent a 302 with a location in header set to `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/...` the IIS proxy replaced it to `http://myserver.com/accounts/o8/...` . which of course was an invalid link.